# Is it possible to change the wireless card on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: wifi, hardware

I'm interested in possibly upgrading my MacBook Pro's wireless card. Is this possible? Can I take apart the MacBook and install it? Is there a guide somewhere on how to do this?

(This isn't because of wireless performance, just lack of stable driver support on Linux.)

Comment: Which exact model of MacBook Pro is it? (secret decoder ring here, if you only have the serial number, which is printed at the bottom: http://www.appleserialnumberinfo.com)

Comment: It's a 8,3, 17" late 2011.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Probably not, but you can use the ExpressCard slot instead

The model you mentioned (17" MacBookPro8,3 late 2011) does seem to have a separate Wifi/bluetooth assembly, but you'll probably have a very hard time finding a matching replacement in both size and connection. I didn't find a disassembled 17" model, but the card in the 15" of the same generation [looks like this](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing-MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Unibody-Early-2011-AirPort-Bluetooth-Board/5886/4) (4 antenna connectors and what is probably some sort of PCI Express cable).

However, since yours is a 17", it does have an ExpressCard slot, where you can stick in a Wifi card of your choosing ([something like this](http://www.ebuyer.com/137543-d-link-xtreme-n-notebook-expresscard-dwa-643)) without even having to take the whole machine apart.

Or patch around your Linux kernel with one of the BCM4331 drivers that are out there, but I assume you've already tried that.

Comment: I'm using the BCM4331 driver, it more or less works, but loses connection intermittently and also conflicts with Bluetooth. Lost about 4 days of my life to figuring that last one out.

Answer (score 1):

The MacBook Pro model you mentioned does have a separate AirPort/Bluetooth card, however, this cannot be changed to a different model.

I'd do what other people have suggested and make use of your ExpressCard slot.